# Scanner read only the first line of a textual file

Tags: java, file, for-loop, java.util.scanner

This is my code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    File source = //


    Scanner s = null;       
    int lineNumber =0;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tagsArray = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        s= new Scanner(source);
    while (s.hasNext()) {

            String[] cols = s.nextLine().split("    ");

            for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                if (cols[i].equals("1"))
                    tagsArray.get(i).add(lineNumber);
                }
            lineNumber++;

        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

When I delete the  for statement it read the whole text file but when I use it it read only the first line 
why?

Comment: I would say that using a BufferedReader would be better than using a scanner for reading files. Have a look at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you get an `Exception`, but you catch and hide it instead of handling it. **This is very bad!** You should at least print the stacktrace of the exception.

You try to access:

```
tagsArray.get(i).add(lineNumber);
```

when `tagsArray` is empty. You need to instantiate each `ArrayList<Integer>` inside `tagsArray` before accessing it.

Comment: It is bad to use the try catch block ?

how Can I handle the Exception?

Comment: Try catch block is good. But doing nothing inside catch block is bad. At least use `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Also, it is better to use { and } after each if or for.

Comment: Rather than a "printf" in a catch block, it'd be honest and declare the `main` to throw an `IOException`.